# Android Studio button layout: Unexpected overlap

Tags: android, overlap

[image]

Why does this overlap?

It's well-placed in the preview, but when you run the app, it's laid out as you see it.

Comment: Please do not post code as an image. Instead, post code as text in the question itself and format it with the `{}` button on top of the editor or CTRL + K.

Comment: `tools:layout_editor_absolute***` are only handled by the layout editor preview, that's why your buttons misplaced, you should add constraints to the buttons.

Comment: How do I add constraints to a button?

Comment: Maybe you need this: https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/

Answer (score 0):

An example to solve overlap:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Button"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"/>
</LinearLayout>
```